# How do I move example.com/profiles/1 to example.com/username with friendly_id with username from user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, profile, friendly-id

I have red docs on friendly_id for rails. It's easy: you set a certain attribute to be the slug.

example.com/username

```
User has_one profile
Profile belongs_to User
```

So you see my dilemma. I have no column username in the profile model. How can I link the user model, username field so that I can do example.com/username with friendly_id?

Surely this is relatively simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a "catch-all" route at the end of your routes file:

```
map.connect ':username', :controller => 'profiles', :action => 'show' (this is for Rails 2.3)
```

And in the profiles controller, method show you check if there is a user with that username, and if it belongs to the current profile

```
def show
  if User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    if @current_user == User.find_by_username(params[:username])  
     # @profile = @current_user.profile
     # render projects#show view 
    else
     # flash error message, because the current user tries to access other users profile (in case your app doesn't allow it)
  else
    # render page not found error 
  end
end
```

I had a similar situation for a projects model, from projects/id => /project_name.
It is a bit easier in your case because in the db you have unique usernames. 
Ah, and no extra gems are involved.

Answer (score 1):

In your `ProfilesController#show`:

```
def show
  @user = User.joins(:profile).where("profiles.username = ?", params[:username])
end
```

Routes:

```
match ':username' => "profiles#show'
```

Optionally, you can add a method to your User model to make your controller cleaner:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def fetch_by_username(username)
    joins(:profile).where("profiles.username = ?", username)
  end
end
```

And in your controller:

```
@user = User.fetch_by_username(params[:username])
```

Comment: I have a profile view with @profile.firstname inside the profiles model there is no username, thanks for the reply but count get this to work.  Table user is like  id|user_id|etc profile table is like |id|user_id|etc

Comment: Tried above example they both don't work The problem is I have no username column in my profile table only a user_id
wich belongs to the user Rather not add extra gems just use default routing to get this up. Still haven't been able to find a working solution maybe anyone an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom method to generate the slug you need.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users

  has_friendly_id :custom_url_method, :use => :slugged

  def custom_url_method
     self.user.username.to_url
  end
```

The to_url is from Stringex gem. You can alternatively use one of Babosa's helper methods provided by Friendly_id itself.

Comment: You say, ou can alternatively use one of Babosa's helper methods provided by Friendly_id itself. What helpers would that be?

Comment: It would be something like 
'"Gölcük, Turkey".to_slug.normalize.to_s #=> "golcuk-turkey"'

You can check out examples at https://github.com/norman/babosa